# iOS on mobile not showing CSS 1px borders correctly

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have a Bootstrap header customized with CSS borders to give it a 2px and 1px shadow effect, like this:

```
<div class="navbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.navbar{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C7C7C7;
}
.header{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #EFEFEF;
}
```

The HTML tags of the page are:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=970" />
```

For some strange reason, when viewing the page in iOS on a mobile device like iPad or iPhone, it doesn't show the borders correctly. Initially when loading it, it shows only 1px of the line and when zooming the page the other 2px are visible but somehow distorted. The full line is not shown.

What could be wrong here? Is this a iOS issue or..?

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's happening on both Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I changed the meta tags to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```